# Sending SQL Reporting server login username & password inside query/post/header

Tags: azure, reporting-services

I need to load Report manually in XML to be able to draw custom diagrams from it.

I would be able to load XML but Azure SQL Reporting Server asks for username and password before returning XML.

Is there way to include username and password in header/query/content?

Comment: As Plan B I could fake posting back username/password form data. But it would not work anymore if that dialog is changed.

Comment: I am looking into it and will add more info on this regard.